# Is there a method to select the current scope within an ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an Angular 1.x MVC set up as such:

```
...

.controller('orderdetailCtrl', ['$scope', 'orderServer', ..., function($scope, orderServer, ...) {

  $scope.refundDetail = function(item) {
    orderServer.refundDetailDialog(item).result.then(function(data) {
      if(data) {
        item.refund_info.refund_balance = data;
      }
    });
  }

  $scope.refundEdit = function(item) {
    orderServer.refundEditDialog(item).result.then(function(data) {
      if (data) item.refund_info.refund_balance = data;
    });
  }

  ...

}]).controller('refundDetailDialogCtrl', ['$scope', 'orderServer', ..., function($scope, orderServer, ...) {

  ...

  $scope.cancel = function() {
    $modalInstance.close($scope.entity.refund_info.refund_balance);
  };
}]).factory('orderServer', [..., function(...) {

  return {
    refundDetailDialog: function(item) {
      return $dialogs.create('/.../xxx.modal.html', 'refundDetailDialogCtrl', item, {
        size: "lg"
      });
    },
    refundEditDialog: function(item){
      return $dialogs.create('/.../xxx.modal.html', 'refundEditCtrl', item);
    }

  ...

  }
}]);
```

Now the parent page has a setup like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="details in entity.refundlist">

...

</tr>
```

Here the repeated "details" is `item` in `$scope.refundDetail`, now the code above works just fine. Out of curiosity, I like to know if I can replace item in the promise of orderServer to the current scope of "details" (meaning to replace `item.refund_info.refund_balance = data`).

I have so far tried:

```
$scope.refund_info.refund_balance = data;
this.refund_info.refund_balance = data;
refund_info.refund_balance = data;
$scope.details.refund_info.refund_balance = data;
this.details.refund_info.refund_balance = data;
details.refund_info.refund_balance = data;
```

None of which worked.

Comment: use `$parent.$scope.`

Comment: where have you been using `refundDetail`? please write the relevant code in HTML

Comment: @pro.mean if u read the code again u will find that is irrelevant to this question. RefundEdit pass back data to RefundDetail and then pass the same data back to OrderDetail's ng-repeat scope.

Comment: @pro.mean u probably meant $scope.$parent, but $parent.what? $parent.$scope will returned undefined.

Comment: ng-repeat create it's own scope that's why if you need to access loop item outside the ng-repeat than use` $parent`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a logical error in this question. When data is passed back to `orderdetailCtrl` through your factory `orderServer`, it is on the scope of `orderdetailCtrl`, instead of the ng-repeat scope "details", which means you cannot select "details" directly. You current method is the only way to select "details".